# Unknown Property Error "Create Apex Property" when creating Visual Forcepage

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, getter, setter

[image: This is the error I'm experiencing when trying to create a Visual Force page]

I am attempting to save a Visual Force page that is accepting input values from a flow and passing them into an invocable method. It keeps saying the custom object I'm using in the invocable method is 'unknown?'

I tried creating a setter and getter for the Intake__c object, but that didn't work.

Any ideas on why I'm getting this error?

**Here is he code for the VisualForce Page**

```
    <apex:page controller="PackingListQueryController" renderAs="pdf" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false">
<apex:repeat value = "{! FilteredIntakes}" var = "oneItem">
    <html>
    <head>
        <style>
            @page {
                size: letter;
                margin: 25mm;
                @top-center {
                    content: "{! oneItem.name }";
                }
                @bottom-center {
                    content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
                }
            }
            .page-break {
                display:block;
                page-break-after:always;
            }
            body {
                font-family: Arial Unicode MS;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Intake Details">
        <apex:pageBlockSection >
        <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" class="print-friendly">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Parent Name</th>
                            <th>Household</th>
                            <th>Delivery Type</th>
                            <th>Delivery Date</th>
                            <th>Delivery Time</th>
                            <th>Intake Status</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                                <th>{! Intake__c.Parent_Name__c }</th>
                                <td class="tableContent">{! oneItem.Household__c }</td>
                                <td class="tableContent">{! oneItem.Priority__c }</td>
                                <td class="tableContent">{! oneItem.Delivery_Date__c }</td>
                                <td class="tableContent">{! oneItem.Delivery_Time__c }</td>
                                <td class="tableContent">{! oneItem.Intake_Status__c }</td>
                            </tr>
            </table>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Intake Details">
    <apex:pageBlockSection >
        <apex:outputField value="{! oneItem.Parent_Name__c }"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{! oneItem.Household__c }"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{! oneItem.Priority__c }"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{! oneItem.Delivery_Date__c }"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{! oneItem.Delivery_Time__c }"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{! oneItem.Intake_Status__c }"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Baby Wipes and Formula">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!oneItem}" var="Baby Wipes and Formula">
       <apex:column value="{!oneItem.Baby_Wipes_Num__c}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!oneItem.Baby_Formula_Num__c}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!oneItem.Formula_Type__c}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Diaper Boxes">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Intake__c}" var="Diaper Boxes">
       <apex:column value="{!oneItem.Diaper_Boxes_Newborn__c}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!oneItem.Diaper_Boxes_Size_1__c}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!oneItem.Diaper_Boxes_Size_2__c}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!oneItem.Diaper_Boxes_Size_3__c}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!oneItem.Diaper_Boxes_Size_4__c}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!oneItem.Diaper_Boxes_Size_5__c}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!oneItem.Diaper_Boxes_Size_6__c}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!oneItem.Diaper_Boxes_Size_7__c}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Pull Ups">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!oneItem}" var="Pull-up Boxes Boys">
       <apex:column value="{!oneItem.Pull_Ups_Boys_Size_2T_3T__c}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!oneItem.Pull_Ups_Boys_Size_3T_4T__c}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!oneItem.Pull_Ups_Boys_Size_4T_5T__c}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!oneItem.Pull_Ups_Girls_Size_2T_3T__c}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!oneItem.Pull_Ups_Girls_Size_3T_4T__c}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!oneItem.Pull_Ups_Girls_Size_4T_5T__c}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </body>
   </html>
</apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

**Here is the code for the controller the VF Page is pointing to**

```
public with sharing class PackingListQueryController {
//properties used to pass data between VF page and the savepdf method 
public static List<Intake__c> filteredIntakes {
    get { return filteredIntakes; }
    set { filteredIntakes = new List<Intake__c>(); }
}
public static Intake__c intakes {get; set;}

//intake Intake_Status__c = "Approved" & Partner_Intake__c = TRUE
@InvocableMethod(label='Get Filtered Intake Records' description='Get filtered intake records from yields of the flow, filter them again, and return the remaining records')
public static List<Intake__c> getIntakes(List<Request> params){
    Date filterStartDate;
    Date filterEndDate;
    String filterCity;
    Integer i = 0;
    //[[{startDeliverDate: 2022-01-01, endDeliveryDate: 2022-01-10, city: null}]]
    filterStartDate = params[0].startDeliveryDate;        
    System.debug('Filtered Start Date: ' + filterStartDate);        
    filterEndDate = params[0].endDeliveryDate;
    System.debug('Filtered Info: ' + params[0]); 
    // filterStartDate = Date.newInstance(paramStartDate.year(), paramStartDate.Month(), paramStartDate.Day());
    // filterEndDate = Date.newInstance(paramEndDate.year(), paramEndDate.Month(), paramEndDate.Day());
    filterCity = params[0].city;
    if(String.isNotBlank(filterCity)){
        filteredIntakes = [SELECT Id, Name, Street_Address__c, City__c, State__c, Zip_Code__c, Priority__c, Number_of_Families_Served__c, Number_of_Children_Served__c, 
                             New_Families__c, Diaper_Boxes_Newborn__c, Diaper_Boxes_Size_1__c, Diaper_Boxes_Size_2__c, Diaper_Boxes_Size_3__c, Diaper_Boxes_Size_4__c, 
                             Diaper_Boxes_Size_5__c, Diaper_Boxes_Size_6__c, Diaper_Boxes_Size_7__c, Pull_Ups_Boys_Size_2T_3T__c, Pull_Ups_Boys_Size_3T_4T__c, Pull_Ups_Boys_Size_4T_5T__c,
                             Pull_Ups_Girls_Size_2T_3T__c, Pull_Ups_Girls_Size_3T_4T__c, Pull_Ups_Girls_Size_4T_5T__c
                             FROM Intake__c
                             WHERE Intake_Status__c = 'Approved' AND Partner_Intake__c = TRUE
                             AND Delivery_Date__c >= :filterStartDate AND Delivery_Date__c <= :filterEndDate
                             AND Priority__c = :filterCity LIMIT 10];
    } else {
        filteredIntakes = [SELECT Id, Name, Street_Address__c, City__c, State__c, Zip_Code__c, Priority__c, Number_of_Families_Served__c, Number_of_Children_Served__c, 
                            New_Families__c, Diaper_Boxes_Newborn__c, Diaper_Boxes_Size_1__c, Diaper_Boxes_Size_2__c, Diaper_Boxes_Size_3__c, Diaper_Boxes_Size_4__c, 
                            Diaper_Boxes_Size_5__c, Diaper_Boxes_Size_6__c, Diaper_Boxes_Size_7__c, Pull_Ups_Boys_Size_2T_3T__c, Pull_Ups_Boys_Size_3T_4T__c, Pull_Ups_Boys_Size_4T_5T__c,
                            Pull_Ups_Girls_Size_2T_3T__c, Pull_Ups_Girls_Size_3T_4T__c, Pull_Ups_Girls_Size_4T_5T__c
                            FROM Intake__c
                            WHERE Intake_Status__c = 'Approved' AND Partner_Intake__c = TRUE
                            AND Delivery_Date__c >= :filterStartDate AND Delivery_Date__c <= :filterEndDate LIMIT 10];
    }
    for (Intake__c intake : filteredIntakes) {
        System.debug('Filtered Intake Id: ' + intake.Id);
    }
    // for (intakeList < filteredIntakes.length(); i++){
    //     System.debug('Filtered Intake Id: ' + filteredIntakes[i].Id);
    // }
    System.debug('Count Record: ' + filteredIntakes.size());
    returnFilteredIntakes(filteredIntakes);
    return filteredIntakes;
}
public static List<Intake__c> returnFilteredIntakes(List<Intake__c> intakeRecords) {
    return intakeRecords;
}

//Inner class to store additional params to be stored in a list 'Request'
public class Request {
    @InvocableVariable(label='Starting Delivery Date' required='true' description='Starting Delivery Date')
    public Date startDeliveryDate;
    @InvocableVariable(label='Ending Delivery Date' required='true' description='Ending Delivery Date')
    public Date endDeliveryDate;
    @InvocableVariable(label='City' description='City')
    public String city;
}
public class Response {
    @InvocableVariable(label='Success' description='Successful execution of batch job' required=true)
    public Boolean success = true;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You didn't use the `standardController`/`extensions` notation, so Visualforce thinks that `{! Intake__c.Parent_Name__c }` is referencing a property named `Intake__c` (which is impossible, as property names can't have `__` in them). I think you meant `{!intakes.Parent_Name__c}` or possibly `{!oneItem.Parent_Name__c}`. Either way, that doesn't appear to be in your query, so I'd expect a SOQL error here.

Further:

```
get { return filteredIntakes; }
set { filteredIntakes = new List<Intake__c>(); }
```

Will never accept a list of values from the query, it will always be an empty list, as that's how you've defined the setter. It should be simply:

```
{ get; set; }
```

To use the default getter and setter.

Finally, it's not really clear why you'd have a Flow call a Visualforce page to call an InvocableMethod. Under ordinary circumstances, the Flow directly calls the InvockableMethod using an Apex Action.